# Git CMD is not working and freezes on one command

Tags: git, heroku

Whenever I launch Git CMD and try to do this specific cmd it doesn't work at all. It just freezes.

Heroku login

After I do the command, it says "The system cannot find the file path specified"
When Heroku login just asks me for my email and password.

I have tried to re-install already.

https://gyazo.com/a94f0a630781eae9b74f4096dc56d3ef

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid posting screenshots and try to describe your issue better.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with git; you're trying to use the heroku command line tool, but Windows can't find it in your `PATH`.

If you installed the CLI tool and it had something about being added to `PATH`, try restarting your computer. Otherwise, learn about `PATH` and how to add stuff there.

E.g. [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)